# Ng-repeat table td style not loading properly

Tags: angularjs

I am having some problems with my table `<td>` after I use ng-repeat inside `<tr>`. The problem occurs after I add ng-repeat inside the `<tr>`. I lost the `<td> <td>` row style. Take a look at the following images.

**Now it looks like the below screenshot.**

[image]

**Before the table it looks like the below image.**

[image]

Code which I used for displaying is the following:

```
 <table>
 <tr>
     <th>Ref No</th><th>Referance Date</th><th>Phone Model</th><th>Customer Name</th><th>Customer Phone</th><th>Transfer</th><th>Take Print</th>
 </tr>
  <tbody>
<tr ng-repeat="x in Approve"><td> {{ x.ref_no }} </td><td> {{ x.ref_date }} </td><td> {{ x.model_name }} </td><td> {{ x.c_name }} </td><td> {{ x.c_phone }} </td><td><a href="more.php#?id={{ x.ref_no }}"><button class="button">Transfer</button></td><td><a href="print.php?id={{ x.ref_no }}"><button class="button">Print Log</button></td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Controller code is the following.

```
$http.get("api/transfer_api.php").then(function (response) {
$scope.Approve = response.data.message;
});
```

**Table Style Code:**

```css
            #main-content table {
            width: 100%;
            border-collapse: collapse;
            }

            #main-content table thead th {
            font-weight: bold;
            font-size: 15px;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
            }

            #main-content tbody {
            border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
            }

            #main-content tbody tr {
            background: #fff;
            }

            #main-content tbody tr.alt-row {
            background: #f3f3f3;
            }

            #main-content table td,
            #main-content table th {
            padding: 10px;
            line-height: 1.3em;
            }        

            #main-content table tfoot td .bulk-actions {
            padding: 15px 0 5px 0;
            } 

            #main-content table tfoot td .bulk-actions select {
            padding: 4px;
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            }
```

Comment: Its not a problem with your ng repeat

Comment: Well, how is the style supposed to be applied? You haven't added any CSS class or style to the table, nor to the tr, not to the tds. Look at the code of the correct table to understand how this style is obtained (or to the documentation of your CSS framework), and fix your code.

Comment: Let Me update my question with the style code.

Comment: So you need to add the alt-row CSS class to each odd (or even) tr. Use ngClass (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) and the $odd (or $even) scope variable created automatically by ng-repeat (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat). Or even simpler, use ngClassOdd https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClassOdd) or ngClassEven (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClassEven).

Comment: Can you show Me an example?

Comment: You can also use nth-child to style the alt-row instead of adding a class: `#main-content tbody tr:nth-child(:even) {
            background: #f3f3f3;
            }` and style it using CSS.

Comment: Where do I need to add this? I tried to add them in the CSS Style. but nothing happen.